# How can i assign javascript array to Ftllist?

Tags: javascript, jquery, freemarker

i have a list of values in javascript and the variable name is **array** with the values
['1','2','3'].here i want to assign this array values into a list in **ftl** file called list.
actually am trying to get checkbox value through **js** and assigning to a list which is the **ftl** file.

help me to overcome this issue.

Answer (score 0):

FreeMarker runs on the server before the JavaScript runs on the client, so what you want is impossible. Or at least the way you want to do it, it is. You had to post that array back to the server (with a form or with AJAX), etc.

Answer (score 0):

You have to send the list of values via ajax call and refresh a div to show new results.
since freemarker is a templating engine that runs on server to generate the html pages you will not be able to send any objects,lists, etc... to freemarker I could show you an example if you want.